# Symfony 3 Bootstrap form theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

Default bootstrap field was rendered like this :

```
<div class="checkbox">

        <label>
           <input type="checkbox" id="form_checkbox" name="form[checkbox]" required="required" value="1" /> Checkbox
        </label>
    </div>
```

I would like to render it like this :

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="form_checkbox" name="form[checkbox]" required="required" value="1" />
    <label for="form_checkbox">
        Checkbox
    </label>
</div>
```

thanks for help.

Comment: Can you add any question for this topic?

Comment: Are you using the default templates (Symfony 2.6+) or are you using MopaBoostrapBundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your own template for the form and re-define how it will be rendered.

```
twig:
    exception_controller:  twig.controller.exception:showAction
    form_themes:
        - MyBundle::form.html.twig
```

In `form.html.twig`

```
{% use "bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig" %}

{% block checkbox_widget -%}
   <!-- Do whatever you like here-->
{%- endblock checkbox_widget %}
```

Comment: {% block checkbox_widget -%}
   <!-- how to show the label and widget here ? -->
{%- endblock checkbox_widget %}

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry Malyshenko is right, you need to use template for your form.

Try something like that for your twig block:

```
{% block checkbox_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
            {{ form_label(form) }}
        </label>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```